# Network protocol of Puppet

Tags: networking, puppet

I want to know, how puppet `master` process and `agent` process interacts with each other using network. I mean, what exactly occurs, when `master` process send commands from manifest to `agent` process and similarly from `agent` to `master` with error codes? They are creating own packages with commands such

```
`exec {"command"}`
```

or maybe creating packages with whole manifest and then sends they?

Comment: Not tempted to read the easily available and very clear documentation?

Answer (score 5):

The process, roughly:

- Agent runs, requests its catalog from the master via HTTPS API call (authenticated by client certificate).
- Master compiles the catalog for that node from the local manifests and modules on the master and using the data the node sent.  Master sends catalog to node in response to request.
- Agent applies catalog

The catalog contains all of the configuration resources for the node to apply, so that's the mechanism used to deliver them.